# JPA eclipselink, mysql/myisam bulik insert

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, transactions, myisam

What is the best way inserting a lot of objects to mysql/myisam table via JPA?

for example

```
for (DataObject entity : dtoList) {
                    try {

                        em.getTransaction().begin();

                        System.out.println("Saving : backend " + count);
                        entity.setInsertdate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        entity.setUpdatedate(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        entity.setStatus(CommonConstants.ACTIVATED);
                        //System.out.println("Real Save one: ");
                        System.out.println("Persists : backend ");
                        em.persist(entity);
                        em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Does not work for myisam. I knwo what myisam does not support transactions, but what is the best way for bulk insert from JPA code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solution is simple just added

```
em.flush();
```

after persist.

Comment: which is pointless since _commit_ does a _flush_. You are committing 1 object per transaction in your posted code; perhaps you meant to have the object loop within the transaction, not outside it